# Burn-in Text Animation does not work well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to someone to look at my code, and tell me how to force my text animation fades out with hamburger menu click event,but only in the same way how it fades in.I tried many different variations but nothing works.
Any help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 /* hamburger menu */
 $('.menuToggle').hover(function () {
  $('.menuToggle span').toggleClass('spanWithShadow');
  $(this).toggleClass('menuTransform');
  $(this).click(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.removeClass('active');
    flag = false;
    headerText();
   }
   else {
    $this.addClass('active');
    flag = true;
    headerText();
   }
  });
 });
});
/*header text*/
var flag = true;
var headerText = function () {
 var $about, $work, $contact;
 var s,
  textLetters = {
   settings: {
    lettersAbout: $('.js-about'),
    lettersWork: $('.js-work'),
    lettersContact: $('.js-contact'),
   },
   init: function () {
    s = this.settings;
    this.bindEvents();
   },
   bindEvents: function () {
    if (flag == true) {
     $about = $('.js-about').text('About');
     $work = $('.js-work').text('Work');
     $contact = $('.js-contact').text('Contact');
     s.lettersAbout.html(function (i, el) {
      var text = $.trim(el).split("");
      return '<span>' + text.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
     });
     s.lettersWork.html(function (i, el) {
      text = $.trim(el).split("");
      return '<span>' + text.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
     });
     s.lettersContact.html(function (i, el) {
      text = $.trim(el).split("");
      return '<span>' + text.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
     });
    }
    else {
     $about = $('.js-about').text('');
     $work = $('.js-work').text('');
     $contact = $('.js-contact').text('');
     s.lettersAbout.html(function (i, el) {
      text = $.trim(el).split("");
      return text;
     });
     s.lettersWork.html(function (i, el) {
      text = $.trim(el).split("");
      return text;
     });
     s.lettersContact.html(function (i, el) {
      text = $.trim(el).split("");
      return text;
     });
    }
   },
  };
 textLetters.init();
};
```

```css
html,body {
   height: 100%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(41.5%, 53.7%, 95.5%,0.17);
}

 @font-face {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

.header {
 height: 74.64px;
 display: flex;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 1.8em;
 text-align: center;
}

/*Hamburger menu*/
.menuToggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  width:  52.654px;
  height: 52.654px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 18.66px 0 0 10.66px;
}

.menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  height: 0.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 3rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .3s ease-in-out, width .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin .3s ease-in-out, width .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin .3s ease-in-out, width .3s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin .3s ease-in-out, width .3s ease-in-out, transform .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
}

.menuToggle span:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
}

.menuToggle span:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 1.8rem;
}

.menuToggle.active span:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
}

.menuToggle.active span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

.menuToggle.active span:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 1.3rem;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  z-index: 0;
}

.menuToggle span {
  background-color: rgba(17.3%, 24.3%, 31.4%, 0.9);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.menuToggle.active span {
  background-color: rgba(17.3%, 24.3%, 31.4%, 0.9);
  z-index: 1;
}

.spanWithShadow{
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.6),0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.6),0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.6),0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

.menuTransform {
   transform: scale(1.07);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.07);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.07);
}

/*header letters    */
.menu__header {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu__about {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
  align-self: center;
}

.menu__about span {
  -webkit-animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s ease both;
          animation: letter-glow 0.7s 0s ease both;
}
.menu__about span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.05s;
          animation-delay: 0.05s;
}
.menu__about span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
          animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.menu__about span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.15s;
          animation-delay: 0.15s;
}
.menu__about span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
          animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.menu__about span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
          animation-delay: 0.25s;
}


.menu__work {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
  align-self: center;
}

.menu__work span {
  -webkit-animation: letter-glow 0.6s 0s ease both;
          animation: letter-glow 0.6s 0s ease both;
}
.menu__work span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.30s;
          animation-delay: 0.30s;
}
.menu__work span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.35s;
          animation-delay: 0.35s;
}
.menu__work span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.40s;
          animation-delay: 0.40s;
}
.menu__work span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.45s;
          animation-delay: 0.45s;
}

.menu__contact {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
  align-self: center;
}

.menu__contact span {
  -webkit-animation: letter-glow 0.9s 0s ease both;
          animation: letter-glow 0.9s 0s ease both;
}
.menu__contact span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.50s;
          animation-delay: 0.50s;
}
.menu__contact span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.55s;
          animation-delay: 0.55s;
}
.menu__contact span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.60s;
          animation-delay: 0.60s;
}
.menu__contact span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.65s;
          animation-delay: 0.65s;
}
.menu__contact span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.70s;
          animation-delay: 0.70s;
}

.menu__contact span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.75s;
          animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
.menu__contact span:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.80s;
          animation-delay: 0.80s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes letter-glow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes letter-glow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="menuToggle">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="menu__header">
        <p class="menu__about js-about">
        </p>
        <p class="menu__work js-work">
        </p>
        <p class="menu__contact js-contact"> 
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, it looks like you're removing the text in your menu using javascript if `flag == false`. So your text is just disappearing from the page rather than animating out.

You'll need to write an animation in your CSS that reverses the current animation. Then you could activate that animation with Javascript, and when the animation is complete, *then* remove the text.

Comment: Thank you for your  for suggestion,Katniss.Technically,the text appears in a similar way and after that the animation starts immediately.

Comment: @keyframes textDisappearing {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  }
  77% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
}